# After checking condition need to add a column and assign a value

Tags: r

I have a data frame(final1) with few columns

```
  for(i in final1$Total.Tyres)
  {
   if(final1$Total.Tyres[i] >= 500){
    final1$flag_tyres[i]<-1
   } else {
    final1$flag_tyres[i]<-0
   }
  }
```

I need to check if tires are greater than 500 if so need to assign 1 adding  a new column flag_tyres
when tried the above code give me below error

```
 Error in if (final1$Total.Tyres[i] >= 500) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Did you mean `1:length(final1$Total.Tyres)`?

Comment: oops! how could I miss this, thanks for helping out, works fine now :)

Comment: @user2974951 ... you've spotted the typo. Please post it as answer with explenatory code such Shubhang can select and award it with rep. and we can learn from the mistake. Now its not fully clear to non-R users. This also helps to rid the question from the " unsolved question" department and moves it to the "answered and solved" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider vectorizing your code instead of using `for` to loop over the rows, saves you typing, hassle and is faster:

```
final1$flag_tyres <- ifelse(final1$Total.Tyres >= 500, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, should be `1:length(final1$Total.Tyres)` in the outer loop. Alternatively, you could vectorize the result, as already answered.